# Workflow Manager Backend stop after insalling CU3 Update

Tags: 2013, workflow, server-farm, workflow-manager, workflow2013

Hi we just installed CU3 update in our SharePoint server https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50043 then after restarting the machine the Workflow Manager Backend cannot be started.

I got this error in event logs:

```
The Workflow Manager backend failed to start at location 'WorkflowServiceBackendHost.OnServiceStarted' due to an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The current version of the Workflow Resource Management Store, 1.0.2.0, is older than the running product which is designed for the Workflow Resource Management Store version 1.3.0.0.  Please upgrade the Workflow Resource Management Store.
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Service.WorkflowServiceBackendHost.OnStartCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

[image]

We already tried to restart the service in power shell or in services.exe but nothing works. :(

Is there anything that we need to check to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check the Workflow Manager/Service Bus event logs in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Ok i got the error in the event log see my update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue occurs because of the `Workflow Resource Management Store version` value at `[WFResourceManagementDB].[dbo].[StoreVersionTable]` is still `1.0.2.0` despite you have installed CU3 that should work with Workflow Resource Management Store version `1.3.0.0`.

To overcome this issue , you will need to make the two version identical at `[WFResourceManagementDB].[dbo].[StoreVersionTable]`  and `wfServerUpgradePolicy.config` to be `1.3.0.0` as the following :

- Go to `C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow`
- Open `wfServerUpgradePolicy.config` and make sure that `<wfupgrade targetVersion="1.3.0.0">`
- Run the following two script

  - `WorkflowServiceInstanceManagementDBUpgradeScript.sql`
  - `WorkflowServiceResourceManagementDBUpgradeScript.sql`

[image]

Now the `the Workflow Resource Management Store version` value at `[WFResourceManagementDB].[dbo].[StoreVersionTable]` should be `1.3.0.0` , the `workflow manger backend` should be started.

Comment: For some clarification on how to run the SQL files, You should the SQL files in an SSMS connected to the SQL Server hosting the farm in the following way
- WorkflowServiceInstanceManagementDBUpgradeScript should be run against "WFInstanceManagementDB"
- WorkflowServiceResourceManagementDBUpgradeScriptsql should be run against "WFResourceManagementDB"

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the steps in the post at [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2014/11/19/workflow-manager-backend-service-failure-after-upgrade-to-1-0-refresh/) - while this refers to an earlier version of Workflow Manager, the issue described is exactly the same as yours and the steps to resolve look like they should work for your scenario.

Essentially, you need to manually run the upgrade scripts WorkflowServiceInstanceManagementDBUpgradeScript and WorkflowServiceResourceManagementDBUpgradeScriptsql located in the Workflow Manager install path\1.0\Workflow. These Scripts are shipped as part of the cumulative update for Workflow Manager. Run the scripts manually on any node of the Workflow Manager farm and then check whether everything fires back up.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found the solution in this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2014/11/19/workflow-manager-backend-service-failure-after-upgrade-to-1-0-refresh/

The workflow manager installation cant execute the script in our WorkflowInstance and ResourceManagement DB.

So what i did is to execute the 2 scripts in the databases and the workflow service backend start to run again.

Cheers!